# How to get word list using ISpLexicon::GetWords?

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-synthesis

I'm developping a Text-To-Speech application using Microsoft SAPI. I found out that it is possible to add customized prononciations of words in a dictionnary (correct me if I'm wrong). I implemented a function which allows to add words into this dictionnary. Here is my code:

```
int addPrononciation( const char* addPron, const char* phon )
{
   hr = cpLexicon.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpLexicon );
   hr = cpContainerLexicon.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpLexicon );

   hr = SpEnumTokens( SPCAT_VOICES, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum );
   cpEnum->Item( saveVoice, &cpVoiceToken ); //get saveVoice token defined at line 136
   cpVoice->SetVoice( cpVoiceToken ); //Initialization of the voice

   hr = cpContainerLexicon->AddLexicon( cpLexicon, eLEXTYPE_APP );
   langId = MAKELANGID( LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US );
   hr = SpCreatePhoneConverter( langId, NULL, NULL, &cpPhoneConv );

   int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, addPron, -1, NULL, 0 );
   wchar_t* pronWstr = new wchar_t[ wchars_num ];
   MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, addPron, -1, pronWstr, wchars_num );

   int phonWchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, phon, -1, NULL, 0 );
   wchar_t* phonWstr = new wchar_t[ phonWchars_num ];
   MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, phon, -1, phonWstr, phonWchars_num );

   if(SUCCEEDED( hr ))
   {
      hr = cpPhoneConv->PhoneToId( phonWstr, wszId );
      hr = cpVoice->Speak( phonWstr, SPF_DEFAULT, NULL );
      hr = cpLexicon->AddPronunciation( pronWstr, langId, SPPS_Noun, wszId );
      hr = cpVoice->Speak( pronWstr, SPF_DEFAULT, NULL );
      if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
      {
         printf( "Success\n" );
      }
      else
      {
         printf( "Failed\n" );
      }
   }

   cpEnum.Release();
   cpVoiceToken.Release();
   cpContainerLexicon.Release();
   cpLexicon.Release();
   cpPhoneConv.Release();
   delete new wchar_t[ wchars_num ];
   delete new wchar_t[ phonWchars_num ];

   return true;
}
```

Now I would like to list these words using **ISpLexicon::GetWords**.

I already read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720510(v%3Dvs.85)) on the Microsoft website and tried to implement the function, but I can't figure out how to initialize the variable `spWordList`.

Here is my code:

```
 ZeroMemory( &spWordList, sizeof( spWordList ) );
 if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
 {
     hr = cpLexicon->GetWords( eLEXTYPE_APP, &dwGeneration, &dwCookie, &spWordList );
     printf( "Words: %ls\n", spWordList ); //print words but the output is null
 }
 CoTaskMemFree( spWordList.pvBuffer );
```

I'm triying to print the words, but the output is null. I think the `spWordList` variable is not initialized. Here is a screenshot of the variable values.

[image: Variable values]

How can I initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to initialize `spWordList`. You have to replace `eLEXTYPE_APP` with `eLEXTYPE_USER`. However, you can keep both of them like I did. Below you will find an example on how it lists the words.

```
ZeroMemory( &spWordList, sizeof( spWordList ) );
hr = S_FALSE;
if( hr == S_FALSE )
{
  hr = cpLexicon->GetWords( eLEXTYPE_USER | eLEXTYPE_APP, &dwGeneration, &dwCookie, &spWordList );
  for( spWord = spWordList.pFirstWord; spWord != NULL; spWord = spWord->pNextWord )
  {
     for( spWordPron = spWord->pFirstWordPronunciation; spWordPron != NULL; spWordPron = spWordPron->pNextWordPronunciation )
     {
        printf( "Words in dictionnary: %i\n", dwGeneration );
        printf( "Word: %ls\n", spWord->pszWord );
        //you can also display the pronunciation of words if you wish
     }
  }
}
CoTaskMemFree( spWordList.pvBuffer );
```

In the code, I loop through the entire dictionnary. Notice that the listed words are displayed randomly. I'll update my answer if I find other important information about **ISpLexicon::GetWords**